# How can i make a .XIB from .h and .m files?

Tags: xcode, uiview, sdk, xib

I'm working on an existing project which I basically need to create a .XIB
so I can then put in UIToolbar and UIButtons ect.

On the App already it has a Tab bar but has been inputted through code and not the Interface Builder.

I would appreciate any guidance on my problem.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic code that does this for you.  You'll need to look in the code, find all UIView instances that need to go into the nib and manually create it.  Then you'll have to be sure to set the frame of each of them to the same positioning as what is defined in the code.  Finally, you'll have to be sure to remove all of that from the code (once it is fully migrated to the nib).  Finally, you'll have to be sure that the components are referenced only after the nib has fully loaded (which might not have been the case in the current code).

Why not keep the components in the code (and just use nibs for new views)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I am new to Xcode, but learning at a rapid rate. I want to put the effort into understanding your feedback. Currently what you have explained is a little bit complex for me. I am now in the process of researching into what you have explained. Kind Regards. R

Comment: I would recommend starting with a new project before you try to tackle changes to an existing one.